# Workday Studio- Xpath Boolen Expression Failing to Return Value on Targeted XML Element

Tags: xml, xslt

I am working in Workday Studio doing an integration that retrieves data from a report, which has been set as a report as a service.  This report retrieves student demographic information.  The requirements of this integration necessitate that I retrieve data for the current academic period, the succeeding (future) academic period, and the previous academic period.  Then I must remove duplicate student records.  The student record that needs to be retained in the output, assuming duplicate records for a particular student do exist, are prioritized in this order regarding academic period: future > current > previous.

Because I need to call this report three times, I must aggregate the three report outputs, which are based on academic period, back into ONE XML file.  Once I aggregate them back together, then I run an XSL transformation to remove the duplicate student records, while retaining a single record.  I have this logic figured out.  This is not my issue.

But this is the contextual backdrop for my issue.

The issue itself that I'm having, has to do with an expression inside of an EVAL step, that uses Xpathing.  Currently, when I run the integration, there is no data inside of the report filtering on the future academic period.  This information has yet to have been entered inside of our student tenant.  So I want to run an Eval step to determine whether or not that the report is outputting empty data.

If the report output is empty, I want to reroute my Studio integration to avoid aggregating the data altogether. Instead I want reroute to call a local-out that does logging.

I'm attempting to use xpathB as a function to determine this.  However, I haven't been able to get the Xpath expression to properly target the XML element and return an appropriate true or false value.

xpathB is a boolean function that supposedly will return true or false based on whether a value for the targeted element is found.  (this is my understanding of it)

This is what I have tried inside of an EVAL step.  Here are my expressions:

Initialize a property:

```
props['notEmpty'] = false;
```

then reassign the property value based on xpath expression:

```
props['notEmpty'] = parts[0].xpathB('wd:Report_Data/wd:Report_Entry[1]') == true ? true : false;
```

[Evaluate Expression with xpathb](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3p7lH.png)

Here is an image of the context message that should be evaluating to true, but does not:

[The Root XML and immediate child XML element in context message that evaluate expression is targeting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eazC4.png)

Please let me know if you see an issue with my expression.

I've also tried to use:

```
props['notEmpty'] = parts[0].xpathB('wd:Report_Data/wd:Report_Entry') == true ? true : false;
```

without including [1] on `wd:Report_Entry`.  However this fails to return a value of true as well.

Comment: Why the xslt tag when all you show is perhaps JavaScript evaluating XPath?

Comment: First of all: never post code as images, it's useless. Seems you need to add the namespace argument `parts[0].xpathB('wd:Report_Data/wd:Report_Entry', 'wd urn:com.etc.etc')`